# How to return a cookie from an ASP.NET Core Auth Cookie in a Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently have a razor page where I return a cookie and it works great. However, I am developing a SPA which uses VueJS so I have created an API to directly communicate with. I have converted my code from the Razor Page to the controller but I am not sure how I actually return the cookie when the user tries to log in. If there is a match I want it to return the cookie and create the cookie. As of now I get a 400 code as if this request is not working. Any thoughts what could be wrong with this?

```
    public class LoginController : Controller
{

    private readonly LoginDBContext _context;
    private string connectionString;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public LoginController(LoginDBContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _context = context;
        connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStrings:MMCARMSContext"];       
    }

    // GET: HomeController
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok(new { Result = "Test" });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] string Username, [FromForm] string Password, [FromForm] bool RememberMe)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
        {
            var users = _context.UsersAccountsTbl
                .Where(a => a.Username == Username)
                .Select(a => new { a.InternalUserNumber, a.Username, a.Password })
                .ToArray();

            if (users.Length == 1) //if we have more than 1 result we have security issue so do not allow login
            {

                var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<string>();
                //To use you need to has with var hashedPassword = passwordHasher.HashPassword(UserName, Password);
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(passwordHasher.HashPassword("Username", "password"));
                var user = users.First();

                if (passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.Username, user.Password, Password) == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
                {
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.InternalUserNumber.ToString())
                    };

                    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                    if (RememberMe)
                    {
                        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                            new AuthenticationProperties
                            {
                                IsPersistent = RememberMe,
                                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(2)
                            });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
                    }
                    return Ok(new { Result = "Cookie has been created!" });
                }
                else
                {
                    return Ok(new { Result = "Password is incorrect!" });
                }

            }

            return Ok(new { Result = "Username or Password does not exist!" });
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok(new { Result = "Username or Password invalid!" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved? Do you still need any further assistance on it?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the cookie in the HttpResponse, this way the cookie gets added when the client receives the response from your controller:

```
HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("LastVisit");
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

MyCookie.Value = now.ToString();
MyCookie.Expires = now.AddHours(1);

Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.cookies?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Can I not send the cookie created from identity framework as I have shown in my code above? Is that was HttpContext is doing? Most of the examples of how to create a auth cookie seemed to use identity so not sure how this compares security wise.

Comment: Afaik and for my understanding what is best practice is, is to generate a token on the api which holds all claims of a user and send it to the client via a SignInResultDto. For example I am currently doing this with the JWT Authentication Scheme which sends the token back to my Angular app. Then it's the client's responsibility to store the token in a cookie (or where ever you want to provide a logged in state in your application). Then with every http request I am adding the token to the headers of the request so the api knows which user is trying to activate an action endpoint.

Comment: I am not opposed to this approach however how does the cookie renew for every request? Or does this approach result in the cookie expiring in an hour. Also does this approach not require adding anything to startup class or configure services?